# How to make a single page application?

Tags: single-page-application

## WHAT I'm trying to do:

What resources are there to learn about building Single Page Application's?

## WHAT I've already tried:

Looking into, react, vue and angular's spa-routers, but they were super confusing and hard to use. I want something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the best option ended up being building my own router using jquery, like the following pseudocode:

```
on hash change:
get window.location.hash + '.html' 
document.body.appendChild (response)
```

This allowed me to understand how the single page application worked and split my code into separate HTML files which I needed for organization and simplicity.